# Tangent parallel to the initial line for polar equation =, can r^2 be used instead?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, polar-coordinates

Given a formula for a *polar equation*: 
$$\ r^2 = a^2 \cos^22 \theta  $$

It could be said that to find the points parallel to the initial line, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d (r\sin\theta)}{d\theta} = 0$$

As $$y^2 = r^2 \sin^2\theta$$

It can be said that 
$$y^2 = a^2 (1-2\sin^2\theta)(\sin^2\theta) $$
$$y^2 = a^2 (\sin^2\theta - 2\sin^4\theta) $$

So to now find the points at which it is parallel to the initial line, I assumed that the square root of $y^2$ should be taken before it is differentiated and equated to $0$.

ie: 
$$ y = a \sqrt{ (\sin^2\theta - 2\sin^4\theta)} $$
then 
$$ \frac{d (a \sqrt{ (\sin^2\theta - 2\sin^4\theta)})}{d\theta} = 0 $$

and solve as such.

However after looking at the answers, the question was meant to be solved by differentiating $y^2$ and setting that to $0$ instead:

> [image: solution]

I cant figure out why the solution uses $$\frac{d (y^2)}{d\theta} = 0$$
rather than: $$\frac{d y}{d\theta} = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done this way for ease of calculation. $y$ will be maximum when $y^2$ is maximum.

Comment: You mean minimum right? And only with the form $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ the minimum is the same as $y^2=1+x^2$.

Comment: Thank you, I cant believe I forgot to consider that, when the gradient of y is zero, the gradient of y^2 is also zero